# How to format datatable by rows in R

Tags: r, datatable

I know how to format values by columns in a datatable but I can't seem to find a good way to format them by rows.

For simplicity sake, I'm using `mtcars` as an example. The following code will format the first and the third columns as percentage. But how can I set the first and the third rows as percentage?

```
datatable(mtcars[1:5,]) %>% formatPercentage(c(1,3), digits = 2)
```

Comment: For *storage* and calculations, you cannot: in a `data.frame` (and `data.table`), each column must be the same class or type, such as `character`, `integer`, `numeric`. With `DT::datatable` (please be explicit with packages in questions), it still provides some ability to sort/filter, so changing what it *looks* like in R will turn it into `character`, which may or may not be what you want. Perhaps if you provide some more context as to "why" you want one or two specific rows formatted different, we can find something in `DT` that does what you suggest.

Comment: @r2evans Thanks for the insight! I'm working on a financial dataset where the 1st and the 3rd rows are returns (%) and the other rows are ratios (Sharpe, information ratio etc.). I'm using `flexdashboard` to build a dashboard.

Comment: Probably you need to transpose your data to make rows as columns.

Comment: As I look at your previous comment, T-T, I think @djhurio's comment is very likely to be appropriate. I'll keep my answer in case case (1) that comment is not strictly true; (2) it's appropriate but you don't want to; or (3) you can use the code for other things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumptions:

- this is an R solution, not specific to `DT` ... perhaps there's a trick within `DT` to do this internally there instead of munging the data
- you aren't using numeric-sorting or similar number-related functions within `DT`; if you are using them, then number-sorting will be wrong (e.g., `"88"` comes before `"9"`)
- @djhurio's comment is not quite applicable to you (because if it is, then do it)

Continuing with your use of `mtcars`.

```
mt <- mtcars[3:8,1:5]
str(mt)
# 'data.frame': 6 obs. of  5 variables:
#  $ mpg : num  22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4
#  $ cyl : num  4 6 8 6 8 4
#  $ disp: num  108 258 360 225 360 ...
#  $ hp  : num  93 110 175 105 245 62
#  $ drat: num  3.85 3.08 3.15 2.76 3.21 3.69
```

Since you want to put percent signs on all columns within one or more rows, then everything in your data will be strings. In R (and some other languages, too), there is no way around that.

I'm going to systematically go through each "class" of column, to demonstrate that you can treat integers separately from floating point, etc. Use all or none of it. Also, for percentages here I'm just appending the percent sign; you will likely need to multiply by 100, too.

```
mt[c(2,4)] <- lapply(mt[c(2,4)], paste0, "%")
isint <- sapply(mt, is.integer)
mt[isint] <- lapply(mt[isint], format, format="%d")
isnum <- sapply(mt, is.numeric)
mt[isnum] <- lapply(mt[isnum], format, format="%0.3f")
islgl <- sapply(mt, is.logical)
mt[islgl] <- lapply(mt[islgl], as.character)
mt
#                    mpg cyl  disp   hp drat
# Datsun 710        22.8  4% 108.0  93% 3.85
# Hornet 4 Drive    21.4  6% 258.0 110% 3.08
# Hornet Sportabout 18.7  8% 360.0 175% 3.15
# Valiant           18.1  6% 225.0 105% 2.76
# Duster 360        14.3  8% 360.0 245% 3.21
# Merc 240D         24.4  4% 146.7  62% 3.69
```

Now for "those two rows". This actually can apply to any number of rows, just update my magical `i` variable in the `lapply`. I first generate a vector of columns that don't already have percent signs, since otherwise you'll be double-percenting them:

```
needspct <- sapply(mt, function(a) all(!grepl("%", a)))
```

and then

```
mt[needspct] <- lapply(mt[needspct], function(d,i) { d[i] <- paste0(d[i], "%"); d; },
                       i=c(3,6))
mt
#                     mpg cyl   disp   hp  drat
# Datsun 710         22.8  4%  108.0  93%  3.85
# Hornet 4 Drive     21.4  6%  258.0 110%  3.08
# Hornet Sportabout 18.7%  8% 360.0% 175% 3.15%
# Valiant            18.1  6%  225.0 105%  2.76
# Duster 360         14.3  8%  360.0 245%  3.21
# Merc 240D         24.4%  4% 146.7%  62% 3.69%
```

For explanation, the function given to `lapply` (and friends) is generally only passed one argument. What really happens, though, is that with

```
lapply(vec, somefunc, a=1, b=1:5, d=someobject)
```

what's actually happening is

```
somefunc(vec[[1]], a=1, b=1:5, d=someobject)
somefunc(vec[[2]], a=1, b=1:5, d=someobject)
somefunc(vec[[3]], a=1, b=1:5, d=someobject)
...
```

I'll leave it up to you to beautify the strings further, as alignment might be important to you.